# A necessary and sufficient condition of Riemann integrable on Jordan measurable set

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, riemann-integration

In Munkres's book *Calculus on Manifold*, page 93, he gives a theorem:

> Let $Q$ be a rectangle in $R^n$, let $f: Q\to \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded function. Let $D$ be the set of points of $Q$ at which $f$ fails to be continuous. Then $\int_Q f$ exists (it means  Riemann integral exists) if and only if $D$ has (Lebesgue) measure zero in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

But he does not give a similar version theorem when the domain is a Jordan measurable set (a subset $S$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is Jordan measurable if and only if $S$ is bounded and boundary of $S$ has Lebesgue measure zero).

He only gives the following theorem below on page 112:

> If $S$ is rectifiable (Jordan measurable), and $f: S\to \mathbb{R}$ is a bounded continuous function, then $f$ is integrable over $S$.

But it is not a necessary and sufficient condition (only sufficient).

**Question:** Do we have the conclusion below?

> Let $S \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be rectifiable (Jordan measurable), $f: S\to \mathbb{R}$ a bounded function, and $D$ the set of points of $S$ at which $f$ fails to be continuous. Then $f$ is integrable over $S$ if and only if $D$ has (Lebesgue) measure zero in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I am not sure whether this is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The general case is that, when $S$ is also a compact set in $\mathbb{R}^n,$ your guess is correct. But in general, $S$ may not be a compact set, for example, $S=\mathbb{Q}^n\cap [0,1]^n.$ However, the Riemann integrability of $f$ is always equal to the Riemann integrability of $\overline{f},$ here $E$ is a large rectangle satisfying $\overline{S}\subset E,$ and
$\overline{f}:E\to \mathbb{R},$ satisfys $ \overline{f}(x)=f(x),\forall\ x\in S, $ and $\overline{f}(x)=0,\forall x\in (E-S).$

Let $f(x)=1,\forall\ x\in S,$ and let $S=\mathbb{Q}^n\cap [0,1]^n,$  then $f$ is continuous on $S,$ but we can see $\overline{f}$ is not continuous at every point of $\partial S.$ But we have $\partial S=[0,1]^n,$ so the Lebesgue measure of $\partial S$ is $1$. So function $\overline{f}$ is not Riemann integrable on $E,$  which means function $f$ is also not Riemann integrable on $S.$